# Does Allah create daughters when happy?

Tags: hadith, allah, authenticity, prophet-musa

I came across a post where Allah tells Musa alaihisalam that He sends daughters to earth when He is the most happy. Does this narration come from a verified source?

> Once Hazrat Moosa (A.S) asked Allah (SWT). .O Allah what do you do
>   when you are happy. .?
>  Allah (SWT) said: 'When i'm happy i make it
>   rain. ."
>  Hazrat Moosa (A.S) asked again...'What you do when you
>   are mch happy . .??
>  Allah (SWT) said: 'I send guests. ."
>   Hazrat Moosa (A.S) then asked "What do you do when you are happy the
>   most??"
>  Allah (SWT) replied "I CREATE DAUGHTERS". .

[My Source](https://www.facebook.com/WomenInMuslimWorld/posts/410885719020164)

Comment: Social media is not a good source, especially when they don't add references in their posts.

Comment: This message has spread all over the internet, especially on SMS sites. The worst part is that none of them mentioned any source for it. I wonder if it's authentic, cause if it's not, then people are being mislead.

Allah knows the best.

Comment: There is a list compiled about all the fabricated hadith about what Moosa's exchanges with Allah. This hadith is not even on this list. It must be relatively new.

Answer (score 1):

The linked Facebook post as well as other websites which quote this report do not mention any source.

A couple of sites claiming to be run by scholars state that they could not find this report:

> We have not seen the Hadith mentioned in the question, however, there
> is a narration about first part of the question which is as under:
>
> عن عمر بن الخطاب قال : حدثت أن موسى أو عيسى عليهما السلام قال : يا رب
> ما علامة رضاك عن خلقك ؟ فقال عز و جل :  أن أنزل عليهم الغيث إبان زرعهم
> و أحسبه إبان حصادهم و أجعل أمورهم إلى حلمائهم و فيهئهم في أيدي سمحائهم
> قال : يا رب فما علامة السخط ؟  قال :  أن أنزل عليهم الغيث إبان حصادهم
> و أحبسه إبان زرعهم و أجعل أمورهم إلى سفائهم و فيئهم في أيدي
> بخلائهم(شعب الایمان :۷۳۹۲)
>
> Translation: Hazrat U’mar R.A. says that I have been told that Moosa
> A.S. or Esa A.S. said, O’ my Rabb! What is the sign of your pleasure?
> Allaah T’aalaa said: (The sign of my pleasure is that) I send rain at
> the time of the growing of crops and I stop it at the time of its
> harvest, and I entrust their affairs (rule) to their wise ones and
> their wealth to the generous people. He A.S. then asked, O’ my Rabb!
> What is the sign of your displeasure? Allaah T’aalaa said, I send rain
> at the time of the cutting of crops and I stop it at the time of its
> growing, and I entrust their affairs (rule) to their stupid and
> less-competent ones and their wealth to the miser people.
>
> واللہ اعلم بالصواب
>
> Answered on: 07 November 2019 | 10 Rabiul-Awal 1441
> Answer By: Mufti Mohammed Ataur Rahman Sajid
> Checked By: Mufti Mohammed Navalur Rahman
>
> https://islamqa.org/hanafi/shariahboard/121230/did-musa-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-really-ask-allah-these-questions/

Hence this report is likely fabricated and is not found in any well known hadith collections.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. This is amazing. I received this text as well. No reference of course and, I noticed it has also been poorly written or translated. Take a look at this part, I don’t think you will understand what does it say;
Allah Almighty says. When I give my man a son. So I tell his son to go and be your father's arm. And when you give me a daughter. So I swear to God that I will be his father's arm.  ???!!!

My thinking is we cannot just say Allah said something we don’t know where it came from. Please think about the importance of that point. When I say where it came from, I don’t mean Which page or Facebook, I am asking about the Islamic authenticity, where is that recorded?
Please don’t forward stories or sayings about Allah SWT or any of the Prophets without the Islamic source.
Your Brother Ashraf.